# ssh hanging when adding -T parameter with specific router

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, dns, git, vpn

I'm having a very strange problem. From a couple of days I'm having problems with git, ssh and vpn but only when using amazon eero router. Using my smartphone hotspot or even just connecting directly to the modem/router I connect to the eero I don't have any problem.

This is the problem: when I try to execute any git command that require an ssh connection the command hang without any output. If instead I execute the same command but not requiring an ssh connection it works fine. Like for example, on the same repository, `git clone https://...` works fine, `git clone git@...` not.

`ssh` itself works fine, I can connect to my servers and also to github, but if I add the `-T` parameter ssh start hanging, trying to connect to github or any other server. After 10/15 minutes of hanging it says me `Connection to server.x closed by remote host`.

Also, in addition to this, if I try connecting to a vpn (I use NordVPN) the vpn connect but I stop having an internet connection.

All these problems, as I said, starts showing only when I connect to the Amazon eero router.

The operating system I'm using is Arch Linux. If, on the same machine, I start windows I'm instead capable both to connect to vpn or execute ssh based git commands

This is what I tried:

- Changing DNS on the eero router
- Changing DNS on the local machine
- Natting the port 22 and 9418 on the eero router and also both there and on the router giving connection to the eero
- Disabling any firewall both on router and on local machine
- Hard resetting the eero router

Nothing of this worked.

Here an example of `ssh -vvv git@github.com` (working) and one of `ssh -Tvvv git@github.com` (not working):

**`ssh -vvv git@github.com` (working)**

```
    OpenSSH_9.5p1, OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/skato/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/skato/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 2: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup github.com:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.4] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-f8b1fc6c
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-f8b1fc6c
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from github.com
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from github.com
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/skato/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:zaBX+3TpV+3eRToKSta/UFkCrA+YnOfS25Ki4179Txg
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/skato/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/skato/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/skato/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/skato/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/skato/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/skato/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/skato/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:zaBX+3TpV+3eRToKSta/UFkCrA+YnOfS25Ki4179Txg
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/skato/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:zaBX+3TpV+3eRToKSta/UFkCrA+YnOfS25Ki4179Txg
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey with RSA SHA256:zaBX+3TpV+3eRToKSta/UFkCrA+YnOfS25Ki4179Txg
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:zaBX+3TpV+3eRToKSta/UFkCrA+YnOfS25Ki4179Txg
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
Authenticated to github.com ([140.82.121.4]:22) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new session [client-session] (inactive timeout: 0)
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received RSA key SHA256:uNiVztksCsDhcc0u9e8BujQXVUpKZIDTMczCvj3tD2s
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ECDSA key SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ED25519 key SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts for github.com / (none)
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-ed25519 key at /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 key at /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-rsa key at /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts2 for github.com / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: 3 server keys: 0 new, 3 retained, 0 incomplete match. 0 to remove
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug1: pledge: fork
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 32000 rmax 35000
debug3: receive packet: type 100
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 3
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 5
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 2
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 76
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 1
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: chan_shutdown_read: channel 0: (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf_empty delayed efd 6/(87)
Hi sk4t0! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug2: channel 0: written 87 to efd 6
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: chan_shutdown_write: channel 0: (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
#0 client-session (t4 [session] r43 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1 io 0x00/0x00)

debug3: send packet: type 1
Connection to github.com closed.
Transferred: sent 3844, received 3076 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 14869.6, received 11898.8
debug1: Exit status 1
```

**`ssh -Tvvv git@github.com` (not working)**

```
    OpenSSH_9.5p1, OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/skato/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/skato/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 2: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup github.com:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.4] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skato/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-f8b1fc6c
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-f8b1fc6c
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from github.com
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from github.com
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/skato/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:zaBX+3TpV+3eRToKSta/UFkCrA+YnOfS25Ki4179Txg
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/skato/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/skato/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/skato/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/skato/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/skato/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/skato/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/skato/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:zaBX+3TpV+3eRToKSta/UFkCrA+YnOfS25Ki4179Txg
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/skato/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:zaBX+3TpV+3eRToKSta/UFkCrA+YnOfS25Ki4179Txg
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey with RSA SHA256:zaBX+3TpV+3eRToKSta/UFkCrA+YnOfS25Ki4179Txg
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:zaBX+3TpV+3eRToKSta/UFkCrA+YnOfS25Ki4179Txg
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
Authenticated to github.com ([140.82.121.4]:22) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new session [client-session] (inactive timeout: 0)
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received RSA key SHA256:uNiVztksCsDhcc0u9e8BujQXVUpKZIDTMczCvj3tD2s
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ECDSA key SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ED25519 key SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts for github.com / (none)
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-ed25519 key at /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 key at /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-rsa key at /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts2 for github.com / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /home/skato/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: 3 server keys: 0 new, 3 retained, 0 incomplete match. 0 to remove
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x20
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug1: pledge: fork
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 32000 rmax 35000
```

and around 13 minutes after:

```
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype keepalive@openssh.com want_reply 1
debug3: send packet: type 82
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
#0 client-session (t4 [session] r43 i0/0 o0/0 e[write]/0 fd 4/5/6 sock -1 cc -1 io 0x01/0x00)

Connection to github.com closed by remote host.
Transferred: sent 3504, received 2784 bytes, in 780.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 4.5, received 3.6
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Comment: Try running ssh with the option "-O IPQoS=none", or add "IPQoS none" to your _.ssh/config_ file. Your router may have trouble with the QOS used for non-interactive sessions. The relevant line in the debug output is the "debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS ..." line.

Comment: Kenster's suspected cause is also described there: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7058

Comment: That's great, it helped me making ssh -T (and so git as well) working, many thanks! I also fixed somehow the vpn problem: I'm using nordvpn and switching from nordlynx (wireguard) to openvpn did the job, but I really don't know why, any idea? If you want to actually answer with your comment as answer (and maybe also a possible reason for why vpn wasn't working with wireguard and it is with openvpn) I'll mark it as the solving answer. Thanks again!